# set delay for 5 sec after one API call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

in my project, I am having one challenge. ie.. I need to call multiple API calls one by one. Here I am using RxJS `flatMap` operator for that. it is working expected. but  my additional requirement is I need to set 10 seconds delay for every API call. I have used 'throttle' operator but It is not working.I have attached my code below. can anyone tell us what I did wrong in my code.

```
public makeSubmitAPI(oncallData): Observable<any> {
        let orderPayload = this.postAPIService.prepareOrderPayload(oncallData);
        let url = "";
        let orderResponse: any;
        return this.apiCallsService.apiCall('placeOrder', orderPayload, 'post', false)
            .map((orderRes: any) => {
                orderResponse = orderRes;
                url = `orders/${orderResponse.data.id}/progress`;
                let progressPayload = this.postAPIService.prepareProgressAPIData(oncallData, orderResponse.data, this.userType);
                return progressPayload;
            }).pipe(throttle(val=> interval(5000)))
            .flatMap(progressPayload => {
                    return this.apiCallsService.apiCall(url, progressPayload, 'post', false).pipe(throttle(val=> interval(5000)))
            })
            .flatMap(progressResponse => {
                return Observable.combineLatest(
                    orderResponse.data.serviceAddresses.map((address, index) => {
                        let fullfilledAPI = this.postAPIService.prepareFullfilledAPIData(oncallData, orderResponse.data, progressResponse, this.userType, index, orderPayload);
                        return this.apiCallsService.apiCall('fullfillment', fullfilledAPI, 'post', false).map(res => res);
                    })
                )
            });
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `concatMap` (instead of the `flatMap` that wrapps the API call) to make the calls one after another and then `delay()` to force that 5s delay you want:

```
.concatMap(progressPayload => this.apiCallsService.apiCall(url, progressPayload, 'post', false)
  .pipe(
    delay(5000)
  )
})
```